# add (assembly) instruction not working like I thought it should

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the line `add (%ecx,%esi,4),%edx`.

I am using gdb to look though code and notice that if use x/d to print the value in ecx, it prints 2 (if I use x/s it prints "/002", idk if this is relevent).

Then the register esi is holding 0x2.

I thought that `add` would work like `edx = ecx + (esi * 4)`, which should be 0xA, but after this edx holds 0x6.

I have looked up the add syntax and I believe I had that right so I am wondering why it comes out as 0x6.

Comment: value from memory is added to `edx`. Values in `ecx` and `esi` are relevant only for the memory address calculation, i.e. `address = ecx + esi*4; edx += value_at(address);` ... the `()` in gas syntax denote memory access (although not everywhere, `mov 123,%eax` is also memory access of address `123`, for constant it needs `$`). Don't expect the assembly syntax to make "logical" sense, and instruction behaviour to make "logical" sense, to the level of some high level language, the instructions are 1:1 HW implemented in CPU, so they follow HW-design logic, and syntax is sometimes  "as is".

Comment: just don't guess anything, find always the proper documentation for whatever is confusing you. If you will keep guessing, you will be like 30% times wrong.

Comment: If you wanted `edx = ecx + (esi * 4)`, you'd use `lea (%ecx,%esi,4), %edx` to do the address math and then put the result in a register instead of loading from it.  [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](//stackoverflow.com/a/46597375)

I'm surprised `add (%ecx,%esi,4),%edx` didn't fault with those inputs; normally 0xA isn't a valid address.  (Linux doesn't even allow mapping the low 64kiB of virtual memory by default, so NULL-pointer dereferences will segfault.)  Maybe you're debugging a kernel / bootloader or something with QEMU's gdb-stub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your assembly is in **AT&T Syntax**, which means the instruction is like the following:

```
movl src,dest
```

The code given actually works like **this**

> Then the register esi is holding 0x2. I thought that add would work like edx = ecx + (esi * 4), which should be 0xA, but after this edx holds 0x6.

It actually works like this: Add the value of `edx` to the value at address (ecx+esi*4)